# Problems starting Java Web Start program on one computer, works fine on another

Tags: windows, java

I'm having problems starting [Freeroute.net](http://www.freerouting.net/) PCB router using Java Web Start. When open the .jnlp file using the Java Web Start Launcher option in Firefox 13 (or when trying to start the web application using KiCAD or manually by downloading the .jnpl file), I get error message that says "unable to launch application" and under details, launch file, it says

```
<html>
<head><title>Error 302: Hotspot login required</title></head>
<body>
<h1>Error 302: Hotspot login required</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and under Exception

```
MissingFieldException[ The following required field is missing from the launch file: <jnlp>]
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.XMLFormat.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.jnl.LaunchDescFactory.buildDescriptor(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.updateFinalLaunchDesc(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.prepareToLaunch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.launch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.launchApp(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main.continueInSecureThread(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.javaws.Main$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I believe that the problem is with my Java settings since on another computer, the application starts fine.

The output of `java -version` on both computers is

```
java version "1.7.0_04"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_04-b22)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.0-b21, mixed mode)
```

I really have no idea what could be causing the error on my computer. As far as I know, all Java settings are at their defaults.

Comment: ti appears by your installed HotSpot version and this computer is 64-bit, is the other computer 32-bit only by chance?

Comment: @techie007 No, as I said, booth are using same versions of Java and on this computer the application used to work  few days ago. Unfortunately, I don't know what could have happened in the mean time.

Comment: @HackToHell I rolled back the question since the problem actually has nothing to to with Firefox. When I try to launch the web application using Java Web Start directly or through another program (KiCAD in this case), same error occurs.